# A lipschitz function $f(x)$ valued in the unit ball has almost everywhere Frechet derivative orthogonal to $f(x)$ if $\|x\|=1$.

Tags: lipschitz-functions, constraints, frechet-derivative

Consider a function $f:R^n\to R^m$ valued in the unit ball $B=\{u\in R^m: \|u\|=1\}$.

Assume $f$ is Lipschitz. By Rademacher's theorem, $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere, i.e., for almost every $x$ there exists a Jacobian matrix $D_f(x)$ such that
$$
f(x+h) = f(x) + D_f(x) h + o(\|h\|).
$$

**Is it always true that for almost every $x$, $\|f(x)\|=1$ implies $f(x)^T D_f(x) = 0$?**

Proof: (is it correct?): if $\|f(x)\|=1$ and $f(x)D_f(x) \ne 0$ then
$\|f(x+h)\|^2 = \|f(x)\|^2 + 2 f(x)^T D_f(x) h + o(\|h\|)$ and we can escape the unit ball in the direction $h = D_f(x)^T f(x)$, a contradiction. Hence $f(x)D_f(x) =0$ necessarily.

Comment: In fact you can use the fact $\|f\|^2 = f^T(x)f(x) = 1$ then take the derivative and apply the chain rule to get the result

Comment: @yili  It is not true that $\|f(x)\|^2=1$ for all $x$ (even in a neighborhood of $x_0$ such that $\|f(x_0)\|^2=1$).

Comment: @yili, I would definitely learn something if you could lay out the argument in full!

Comment: Sorry I can't work it out, maybe there is some chain rule.

Comment: There is a paper maybe helpful https://preprints.sissa.it/xmlui/bitstream/handle/1963/2654/chainmor.pdf?sequence=2&isAllowed=y  But it's a bit sophisticated for more